# Show streaming video to a LG Smart TV

Tags: streaming

I'd like to broadcast videos seen on common web sites (like CNN and such) to my LG Smart TV.

I know I could use dlna or protocols like that to stream a local video file on the TV, but haven't yet found any way to play streaming videos.

Any idea?

Comment: You could use an Apple TV or Chromecast device (note that chromecast only works in  Google Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this.

Some TVs have a built in casting functionally. Since your TV is a Smart TV, there is a chance that you TV could support this.

You could buy a [Chromecast](https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/chromecast/?utm_source=chromecast.com). It costs $35 for non-4k, and $69 for 4k. You can use Google Chrome to cast webpages, but some webpages or apps support it natively. This works on both mobile and computer.

You could also buy an [Apple TV](http://www.apple.com/tv/). The latest one costs $150 for 32 GB and $200 for 64 GB. You can cast from both iOS and macOS. You can use [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/)($20) to airplay from Windows and older macs.

Lastly, you can use the [Amazon Fire TV Stick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZV9RDKK)($40) or the [Amazon Fire TV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U3FPN4U)($90). This would be my last choice, because it doesn't support casting. Instead, you would use apps. The bonus is that you can use the Alexa remote, sort of like the Siri remote.

I would choose the Chromecast, because it isn't very pricey, but it enables you to cast anything to your TV.

Comment: so the only option is though an external device, there's no option by using a TV app

Comment: @Maxxer Your TV could support screen mirroring or chromecasting out of the box

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a Mac (by virtue of the fact you've posted your question here).

My recommendation would be to purchase an Apple TV 3 (not the current model) as these can be purchased at very reasonable prices and will do exactly what you want, and much more.

**What you will need**

Your Mac needs to be running at least OS X Mountain Lion v10.8 or later, and your Mac model needs to fall within the following generations of hardware:

- iMac (Mid 2011 or later)
- Mac mini (Mid 2011 or later)
- MacBook (Early 2015 or later)
- MacBook Air (Mid 2011 or later)
- MacBook Pro (Early 2011 or later)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013 or later)

**NOTES:**

1. You can actually use older Macs to airplay via the use of [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/).
2. If you're actually using Windows, you can also use [AirParrot](http://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/).
3. You can also use an Apple TV 2, but I would opt at least for an Apple TV 3 as it has a number of benefits over its predecessor.